# Android Studio set a string in several textview

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

I'm studying Android Studio and I ended up with a problem, and I needed a light.

I made several `TextView` on my application screen
and when I push a button I would change the contents of all `TextViews` that are on the screen.

In case I was using `findViewById ();` and `setText ();` to change the content of each one of them, and is working well.

More in case are several `TextView` and some of them will receive the same value for example 10 of them I go for the same String and another 3 will receive a different string

Thinking about having multiple `TextViews` that will receive the same string, is there any way to create a kind of clone of it that when it changes the others change together, to decrease repetitive commands?

Comment: I suggest you will consider using a `ListView` and an `Adapter` to update many views with specific data. A good option would be the `ArrayAdapter`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Comment: Ya,use putExtra and getExtra function these are going to be helpful in your case

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution

---

`fun setText(text:String, vararg views:TextView){
  views.forEach{it.setText(text)}
}`

But you should avoid calling findViewById multiple times for same view, it takes a lot of time, so you should cache your textviews, and be aware of state changes.

Right solution

---

If you have more than a few textViews, you should use recyclerview. It allows you to render different type of views, and bind them from your datasource. Here is a [Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview.html) for you.